# Multi-Row function to filter out Duplicates

Tags: sql, oracle, filter, flags, multirow

I'm relatively new at using SQL, So I would like your help regarding a case.

I have the following Table (just a sample):

```
| id | FName_LVL1  | LName_LVL1 | FName_LVL2 | LName_LVL2  |
|----|-------------|------------|------------|-------------|
| 1  | John        | Kennedy    | Marc       | Guy         |
| 2  | John        | Kennedy    | Olivier    | Oslo        |
| 3  | Mike        | Lanes      | Patrick    | James       |
```

I would like to  isolate the duplicates in FName_LVL1 and LName_LVL1

So that the Table looks like this :

```
| id | FName_LVL1  | LName_LVL1 | FName_LVL2 | LName_LVL2  |
|----|-------------|------------|------------|-------------|
| 1  | John        | Kennedy    | Marc       | Guy         |
| 2  | John        | Kennedy    | Olivier    | Oslo        |
```

My idea was to create a flag column with a condition that IF lines Above or below in column FName_LVL1 and LName_LVL1 are the same, then put "1", else "0"

Having a Column looking like this:

```
| id | FName_LVL1  | LName_LVL1 | FName_LVL2 | LName_LVL2  | Flag
|----|-------------|------------|------------|-------------|
| 1  | John        | Kennedy    | Marc       | Guy         | 1
| 2  | John        | Kennedy    | Olivier    | Oslo        | 1
| 3  | Mike        | Lanes      | Patrick    | James       | 0
```

After having a table like this I could just filter and having the result I want to achieve.

That's a way to work I'm used to in Alteryx, but I'm not sure if this is possible using SQL statements, or even if this is the best way to tackle this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the `count()` with *window* function .

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d0510d/4)

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT t.*
    ,CASE 
        WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (
                PARTITION BY fname_lvl1
                ,lname_lvl1
                ) > 1
            THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END AS Flag
FROM t
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d0510d/4/0)**:

```
| ID | FNAME_LVL1 | LNAME_LVL1 | FNAME_LVL2 | LNAME_LVL2 | FLAG |
|----|------------|------------|------------|------------|------|
|  1 |       John |    Kennedy |       Marc |        Guy |    1 |
|  2 |       John |    Kennedy |    Olivier |       Oslo |    1 |
|  3 |       Mike |      Lanes |    Patrick |      James |    0 |
```

Comment: This would go with `count`  but with departmental. There is no analytical function you have involved.

Answer (score 0):

The `no_of_records` is a column that tells you how many times the combination is present in the table. I.e. it will be 2 in your example table

```
select table1.*
from table as table1
inner join
(
  Select FName_LVL1, LName_LVL1, count(*) as no_of_records
  from Table
  group by FName_LVL1, LName_LVL1
) table2
  on table1.FName_LVL1 = table2.FName_LVL1
     and table1.LName_LVL1 = table2.LName_LVL1
     and no_of_records>1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "semi join" subquery to get a result like that:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 t1
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 'Anything' FROM Table1 t2
  WHERE t1.FName_LVL1 = t2.FName_LVL1
    AND t1.LName_LVL1 = t2.LName_LVL1
    AND t1.id <> t2.id
)
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f9c44/3

```
| ID | FNAME_LVL1 | LNAME_LVL1 | FNAME_LVL2 | LNAME_LVL2 |
|----|------------|------------|------------|------------|
|  2 |       John |    Kennedy |    Olivier |       Oslo |
|  1 |       John |    Kennedy |       Marc |        Guy |
```

Answer (score 0):

You may prefer using `LAG` & `LEAD` analytic functions with the contribution of `NVL2` :

```
select n.*,
       nvl2(lag(FName_LVL1||' '||LName_LVL1,1,null) over 
       (partition by FName_LVL1||' '||LName_LVL1 order by FName_LVL1, LName_LVL1),1,0)+
       nvl2(lead(FName_LVL1||' '||LName_LVL1,1,null) over 
       (partition by FName_LVL1||' '||LName_LVL1 order by FName_LVL1, LName_LVL1),1,0) flag
  from names n;

ID FNAME_LVL1   LNAME_LVL1  FNAME_LVL2  LNAME_LVL2  FLAG
--  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  -----
1    John        Kennedy      Marc        Guy         1
2    John        Kennedy      Olivier     Oslo        1
3    Mike        Lanes        Patrick     James       0
```

[***SQL Fiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/881e6/4)

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way is to use partition by clause to have only one table scan.
I have save the output in [Livesql](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/gkhi5nvz97ks7vq4v3xvrg38f)

```
drop table t1 purge;
      create table t1 ( c1 varchar2(20), c2 varchar2(20), c3 varchar2(20), c4 varchar2(20));
      insert into t1 values ('John','Kennedy','Marc','Guy');
      insert into t1 values ('John','Kennedy','Olivier','Oslo');
      insert into t1 values ('not','john','vijay','balebail');
      commit;
      select t1.*, count(c1||c2) over (partition by c1,c2 order by c1,c2  ) flag from t1;
      select t1.*, decode (count(c1||c2) over (partition by c1,c2 order by c1,c2  ),1,0,1) flag from t1;
```

C1  C2  C3  C4  FLAG
John    Kennedy Marc    Guy 2
John    Kennedy Olivier Oslo    2
not john    vijay   balebail    1
Download CSV
3 rows selected.
Statement 7
       select t1.*, decode (count(c1||c2) over (partition by c1,c2 order by c1,c2  ),1,0,1) flag from t1

```
C1      C2      C3      C4       FLAG
John    Kennedy Marc    Guy         1
John    Kennedy Olivier Oslo        1
not     john    vijay   balebail    0
```

Answer (score 0):

Well thank you all ! It seems that there is indeed plenty of solutions regarding that case !

I'll keep dig into it to see what's the one I prefer the most, but thanks to you it give me a good insight on SQL logic

Sorry for the delay in my reply, was away for work